# Elasticsearch 7 unable to create index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create index using following syntax

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "movie": {
            "properties": {
                "year": {"type":"date"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I guess "movie" cannot be child of the "mappings", can someone please help me transform this into Elasticsearch 7 compatible syntax.

I tried using `"movie.year" : {"type":"date"}` but then it fails on following insert statement

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies/movie/109487 -d '
{
    "genre":["IMAX", "Sci-Fi"],
    "title":"Intersteller",
    "year":2014
}'
```

I copied from tutorial of Elasticsearch 6

> "Rejecting mapping update to [movies] as the final mapping would have
>   more than 1 type: [_doc, movie]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 7, there are [no more types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). You need to do it like this.

First, [create the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "year": {"type":"date"}
        }
    }
}'
```

Then, [index your document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies/_doc/109487 -d '
{
    "genre":["IMAX", "Sci-Fi"],
    "title":"Intersteller",
    "year":2014
}'
```

Comment: thank you so much, think link you shared was missing piece.